# how to pass parameters to facebook post dialogbox in android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am using below code for passing the params for facebook dialog but it not work. pls anybody help.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "test message");
    params.putString("description", "test test test");

    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new DialogListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });
```

Comment: The only option is to share a link.

Comment: This is outdated version , They have released V 4.0 few weeks back,  do not use deprecated version now.